# expected declaration specifier error , when declaring an external stack

Tags: c

There are three files :

test.c

```
#include "stack.h"

stackT s2;
StackInit(&s2, 15);

int main(){
 stackT s1;
 StackInit(&s1, 10);

 StackDestroy(&s1);
 return 0;
 }
```

stack.h

```
typedef char stackElementT;

typedef struct {
        stackElementT *contents;
        int top;
        int maxSize;
} stackT;

void StackInit(stackT *stackP, int maxSize);
void StackDestroy(stackT *stackP);
```

stack.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stack.h" 

void StackInit(stackT *stackP, int maxSize)
{
 stackElementT *newContents; 
 newContents = (stackElementT *)malloc(sizeof(stackElementT) * maxSize);

 if (newContents == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient memory to initialize stack.\n");
        exit(1);
        }
 stackP->contents = newContents;
 stackP->maxSize = maxSize;
 stackP->top = -1; 
}

void StackDestroy(stackT *stackP)
{
 free(stackP->contents);
 stackP->contents = NULL;
 stackP->maxSize  = 0;
 stackP->top = -1;
}
```

I really need to have an external stack and

```
stackT s2;
StackInit(&s2, 15);
```

in test.c is my attempt to declare that but compiler gives the following error.

```
test.c:4:11: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
 StackInit(&s2, 15);
           ^
test.c:4:16: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 StackInit(&s2, 15);
                ^~
```

Here is what I have tried:

1. I declared stack s1 inside the main function and didn't get any errors for that.
2. I deleted   `#include "stack.h"`   in test.c and I got
   the same error for the external stack s2.

So my questions are:
What is the error for? How can I declare the external stack without any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call functions at top-level in C, you can only have declarations and definitions. Move the call to `StackInit()` into the `main()` function.

```
#include "stack.h"

stackT s2;

int main(){
    stackT s1;
    StackInit(&s1, 10);
    StackInit(&s2, 15);

    StackDestroy(&s1);
    StackDestroy(&s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can only be called from another function. Imagine functions call like a tree in which the root node is the main() function.

Anyway, besides moving the initialization inside main(), if you really want the struct variable definition outside main you can statically initialize it, just doing what StackInit() would do: a stackElementT array of size 15, contents field pointing to the first element, and the top index initialized to -1.

```
#include "stack.h"

stackElementT elements[15];

stackT s2 = { elements, -1, 15};

int main(){
    stackT s1;
    StackInit(&s1, 10);

    StackDestroy(&s1);
    return 0;
}
```